# Sublime 3 Markdown Build System via Pandoc

Tags: macos, sublime-text-3, markdown, pandoc

I'm trying to write a Sublime-Text-3 build system that will run Pandoc to convert my markdown file to html, and then open the html in my browser. I keep getting a "No Build System" error, and I can't figure out why...

Here's my build config file:

```
// Markdown.sublime-build
{
  "selector": "text.html.markdown",
  "working_dir": "$file_path",
  "shell_cmd": [
    "pandoc",
    "-f", "markdown",
    "-t", "html",
    "-o", "${file/\.md/\.html/}",
    "$file"
  ],
  "shell_cmd": ["open", "${file/\.md/\.html/}"]
}
```

I'm running Mac OS X 10.11. I've read the [Unofficial Documentation](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems/configuration.html).

Comment: What's the output in the console? Did you try and specify the build system, rather than using "Automatic"?

Comment: I did try that. It was the syntax, like you mentioned in your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your build file is invalid JSON, which is likely causing the error message. Sublime Text is forgiving about the [use of comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4183018/1329116), but you will have to escape those back-slashes.
2. Since `pandoc` is not a shell command, you need to use `"cmd"` instead of `"shell_cmd"`. A shell command would be `ls`, `mkdir` etc.

**Valid JSON**:

```
{
  "selector": "text.html.markdown",
  "working_dir": "$file_path",
  "cmd": [
    "pandoc",
    "-f", "markdown",
    "-t", "html",
    "-o", "${file/\\.md/\\.html/}",
    "$file"
    "&&",
    "open",
    "${file/\\.md/\\.html/}"
  ]
}
```

As an alternative, you could always use the [Pandoc](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Pandoc) package for Sublime Text.

Comment: Thank you. That fixes the "No Build System" error. I still have trouble sequencing the two `cmd`s. A little research seems to indicate that Sublime-Text-3 doesn't support multiple `cmd` declarations in a build config file, so I'll have to write a shell script and have my build config call that shell script. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: I had no trouble with her hat either, but the edited version should work as well!

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "cmd": ["pandoc -o \"$file_base_name.html\" \"$file\" && open  \"$file_base_name.html\""],
    "shell": "true"
}
```

works for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
{ 
  "shell_cmd": "pandoc -f markdown -t docx -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}.docx\" \"${file}\" ",
  "working_dir": "${file_path}",
  "selector": "text.html.markdown"
}
```

Updated and working